# iPhone is busy: Making iPhone ready for development - iOS 15 - Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I'm trying to run an app on iPhone 7 with iOS 15.0.2 but I receive this error:

```
iPhone is busy: Making iPhone ready for development
```

I searched online and did everything that was told me to do including:

1. Clean Build (CMD+SHIFT+K)
2. restart both devices
3. wait for 40 plus minutes

But nothing changed, I still receive the same loading error

Comment: are you solve it?

Comment: No I didn’t solve it

Comment: I encountered the same problem. IPhone12 with iOS15.1.1.

Comment: I have been waiting for at least 3 hours now and still waiting . Is this a bug? I am updating to xcode 12.2 and iphone 15.4

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet, it is frustrating, I think it is a bug

Comment: same iphone 7 15.4.1 xcode 13.3.1